# Choose LocalDB version in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, localdb

I'm developing a project in VS2022 with EF6, using localDB as default instance.

My DB is being created code-first and since I have multiple versions of localDB installed, for a matter of compatibility, I wanted the database was created using the 2014 (12.0. 4100.1) version. But it is always created in the 2019 version of LocalDB.

Is there any way to specify the LocalDB Version in the project before the DB creation or at any other point?

Comment: Why, out of interest, would you want to use 2014? 2014 is only in extended support, and only has ~2 years of that left. This would mean you'd need to (at worst) force your user base to upgrade their database in about 2 years time to a supported version.

Comment: Use SQL Server Express instead and pick the desired installer.

Comment: You can set it up as a named instance, then use that name to connect

Comment: @Larnu the project is for study purposes. While coding in Win10 the only external machine I have to test it right now is a Win7 x64 SP1 VM... Not a top notch machine lol. Since the SQL Server 2016 > is incompatible with it, I thought about using the 2014 version.

Comment: @ErikEJ this actually did the job! Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SQL Server Express instead and pick the desired installer